# java.io.IOException:prepared failed:status=0x1

Tags: java, android

Please help me out to resolve this error, I am trying this from past 5 days and unable to resolve it.

As "Text to speach" in android does not have pause state, I am trying to do with mediaplayer to pause and play.

converting string of text to .3gp format and storing in sdcard,till here its working fine, but I am facing problem in mediaPlayer, it is throwing below error

```
07-10 09:12:12.279: D/(13589): temper destination file/mnt/sdcard/tmpaudio.3gp
07-10 09:12:12.279: I/TextToSpeech.java - synthesizeToFile(13589): synthesizeToFile text of length 256
07-10 09:12:12.479: D/MediaPlayer(13589): setDataSource(tmpaudio.3gp)
07-10 09:12:12.489: E/MediaPlayer(13589): error (1, -2147483648)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity$GraphView$2.onClick(PdfViewerActivity.java:651)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
07-10 09:12:12.489: W/System.err(13589):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 09:12:12.489: D/MediaPlayer(13589): start state 0
07-10 09:12:12.489: E/MediaPlayer(13589): start called in state 0
07-10 09:12:12.489: E/MediaPlayer(13589): error (-38, 0)
07-10 09:12:12.529: E/MediaPlayer(13589): Error (-38, 0)
```

Code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {                   
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    if (mBtplay.getText().equals(getString(R.string.play_str))) {
        PdfReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new PdfReader(pdffilename);
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
        int num = mPdfPage.getPageNumber();
        String str = null;
        try {
            str = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(
                                                   reader, num);
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, str);

        File appTmpPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        System.out.println(""
                           + appTmpPath.getAbsolutePath());
        appTmpPath.mkdirs();
        String tempFilename = "tmpaudio.3gp";

        final String tempDestFile = appTmpPath
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/" + tempFilename;
        Log.d("","temper destination file"+tempDestFile);
        mTts.synthesizeToFile(str, myHashRender,
                              tempDestFile);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tempDestFile);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(""+e);

        }
    } else {
        try {
            Log.d("", "pause");

            mBtplay.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str));
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        } catch (Exception pa) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }

        }

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions for you. Try these one by one in given order.

1) Check if the file you are trying to play exists and the path is correct before you play it.

2) Try a different audio format, like mp3.

3) Use a file descriptor instead of the file path, i.e.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pathoffiletobeplayed);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
```

4) Call `reset()` before `setDataSource()`.

1 is obligatory. If no success, try all combinations of 2-3-4.

Comment: i have tried with all these steps problem not yet resolved.if i put in raw folder songs will play, but through /sdcard/file.mp3 giving file not found.But if i check in directory file is present

Comment: Do you have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest file?

Comment: File is saved in sdcard. How to access that file through setdatasource

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether the reference to the media file is Released Properly.
2. Play with an Audio Tool which is present in the system